# Extend Apache XML-RPC to support broader number of ISO8601 types

Tags: java, datetime, xml-rpc, iso8601

I am trying to receive an XML-PRC call with a dateTime.ISO8601 field in it. The caller (which I have no control over) has implemented the call with a QT library that is stripping dashes from the date value.

Is it possible to extend the Apache XML-RPC type converter such that is will accept a broader set if ISO8601 formats? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The XMLRPC "spec" does not include dashes in the iso8601 date.  So, it's not really stripping the dashes.

http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC

Is this a problem with the client implementation?

Comment: Yes, but I have no control over the client. Note, the date with dashes is a valid ISO8601 date, just not the form XML-RPC calls out in the spec.

Comment: Right. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/xml-rpc/message/6753.  BTW -- we gave users the option for receiving the date with the dashes (IIRC, for the Apache XMLRPC client as well).   That has led to quite a few problems with customers ending up configuring the wrong format.  It turned out to be not such a good idea.